# links to Google Play are missing from results of plus.activities.list and plus.activities.get

Tags: google-plus

When sharing links to Google Play apps, the "attachments" block is missing from json returned by calls to plus.activities.list and plus.activities.get
What is the proper way to get the link url for this kind of activities?